# VPS ubuntu apache server - web page

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, web

I bought a VPS server, where I installed apache, mysql, php and phpmyadmin. I created database (like in my local project).

So, now I want to migrate a local project to my server and please, tell me I am  right:

1. Files .php has to be in folder var/www on my apache server? (here is index.html too) and from this folder connect with database?
2. I have to download NPM on ubuntu
3. I have to download GIT on ubuntu
4. Download repo from my github where I've got whole code (webpack dist files, node modules, src and whole config) to /var/www catalog
5. index.html has to be in top-level directory (just in var/www not for example var/www/src

Please help me and tell if I am thinking right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Files .php has to be in folder var/www on my apache server? (here is index.html too) and from this folder connect with database?

It depends on what you set in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. I assume that you installed with default configuration from `apt-get`.

> 5. index.html has to be in top-level directory (just in var/www not for example var/www/src

If for example your source codes are in `/var/www/src` instead of `/var/www`, the just modify the `000-default.conf`. Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName your_domain_name.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/src/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/src>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
            Options -Indexes
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/log/your_log_file.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/your_access_log_file.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache and try open in your browser to see if it works.

As for the database, since you have phpmyadmin, just export the sql data from your local machine and import it into the VPS phpmyadmin.